# rpart change text size in node

Tags: r, plot, decision-tree, rpart

I would like to change the text size of a node in rpart.
The text does not fit into the box of the node if the text is too large. Still, there should be enough space.

```
rpart.plot(pruned_tree_model, type=0,tweak=1.5,leaf.round=0)
```

are there some arguments to add?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can actually change text size in nodes the same way you control text size in normal `plot` --- via the `cex` parameter:

```
library(rpart)
fit <- rpart(Mileage ~ Weight, car.test.frame)

par(mfrow = c(1, 2))
plot(fit)
text(fit)
plot(fit)
text(fit, cex = 0.5)
```

[image]